# Specify Java classpath

Tags: java, classpath, war, program-entry-point

I am on a Linux and have a WAR directory with `WEB-INF/lib` and `WEB-INF/classes` directories. I further have a class with a `main` method.

I want to make java execute the main method and have all libraries on the claspath, so I call

`java -cp /path/to/WAR/WEB-INF/lib/*:/path/to/WAR/WEB-INF/classes/* this.is.my.package.Main`

I get a

`Error: Could not find or load main class this.is.my.package.Main`

However, when I call from inside `WEB-INF/classes` directory

`java this.is.my.package.Main`

I get the Exception because a library class is missing

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ...`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you are not planning on running the war file in an application container e.g. Tomcat, Jetty, Glassfish, etc?

Comment: I am planning that. My webapp spwans other JVMs from inside the *host* webapp, which I plan on doing with this call. If there is any better of doing this I am open for suggestions, but that's not my current issue.

Comment: The classes directory itself must be in the classpath. Not all its files: `java -cp /path/to/WAR/WEB-INF/lib/*:/path/to/WAR/WEB-INF/classes`

Comment: @hansi I was merely trying to make sure you realized that running a war file via the command line was not a typical use case.

Comment: Thanks both. JB Nizet your suggestion solved it for me. If you create an answer I'll mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes directory *itself* must be in the classpath. Not all its files:

```
java -cp /path/to/WAR/WEB-INF/lib/*:/path/to/WAR/WEB-INF/classes
```